# How is grailsApplicaiton initialized in a grails spock unit test?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spock

I have a really basic grails 2.2.4 spock test that doesn't initialize the grailsApplication correctly.

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class SampleUnitSpec extends Specification {

    void "test fixture"() {
        expect:
        Holders.grailsApplication           // This is null and the test fails 
    }
}
```

How can I unit test Services/Controllers that use Holders.grailsApplication?

Comment: Because it is a unit test, and now it only test for`SampleUnit`. So, it won't init grailsApplication or anything esle. If you want to use grailsApplication, you should consider using integration test.

Comment: Have a look at GrailsUnitTestMixin.initGrailsApplication.  It creates a grailsApplication, but the way it is set up is not compatible with Holders.grailsApplication.

Comment: found solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

`grailsApplication` is available to Unit tests by default. Just use it directly (even without declaring it as `def grailsApplication` in tests). Below test should pass. If there is still an element of doubt, print `grailsApplication.config` in `expect:`.

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class SampleUnitSpec extends Specification {

    void "test something"() {
        expect:
            !grailsApplication.config.isEmpty()
    }
}
```

Comment: My class under test uses Holders.grailsApplication to access config and  beans. So the local grailsApplication instance can't be used.